# How would you compare multiple ints in 1 if statement without repeating it?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have some coding in Java to calculate the movement in a virtual camera since the last time a variable was checked. More specifically, this code below:

```
float movementX, movementY, movementZ;                  
movementX = (int) (camX - sectorSize[1]);
movementY = (int) (camY - sectorSize[2]);
movementZ = (int) (camZ - sectorSize[3]);

/*
 * If the variable is below 0
 * then get the absolute value
 * of the movement since the
 * last camera position.
 */
if (movementX < 0) movementX *= -1;
if (movementY < 0) movementY *= -1;
if (movementZ < 0) movementZ *= -1;

if (movementX > 60 || movementY > 60 || movementZ > 60) 
{   
    //Reset the sector size to allow for new points,
    //don't store to save memory (may be changed later).
sectorSize[0] = 0;
}
```

If you need more of the code, let me know. The sectorSize variable stores 0-500 in its [0] value, the former camX in it's [1] value, the former camY in it's [2] value and lastly former camZ in its [3] value. The camX, camY, and camZ are handled by other code (not displayed). removed everything but the code-in-question to keep it tidy.

This code works as-is, but typing "if (a_int_value > an_other_value || etc)" each time is a bit tedious.

Comment: movementX will *never* be > 60 if that code is to be believed. If it is > 0, it will be made negative, an thus will never reach positive numbers. This is quite confusing to say the least. Are you sure that you don't have > mixed up and should be using <? Precision in coding and in questions on SO matter.

Comment: This is the clearest way to do it really, yes it's tedious to type but it's clear and easy to understand

Comment: For my money, I'd simply do `movementX = (int)Math.abs(camX - sectorSize[1]);` Also, what occurs at `"//do something.."`

Comment: This program is for making some basic dot-stars, I keep them in sectors of 500. This is for calculating if I should make a new sector because the camera is far enough away from the former one. And I just realized I did screw up the "<" with ">", adjusted code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a Movement class and encode the parameters for a "legal" movement within it.
Then you can test:  movementX.isValid(). You can also keep a List or create another class to wrap the three axes and have a single isValid() method to test with.

You should consider storing sector sizes in something more descriptive than an array.

Finally, why are you casting your floats to int?  What good can come from that?  If you mean to strip off the decimal, there are much better ways to truncate, or floor/ceiling the value.

Comment: The sector size[0] value has to be an int, as it depicts how many white points there are on a screen ("stars"). The decimal isn't that important in this calculation, but it is for moving, so I have the camX, camY, and camZ values as floats.

Comment: It's mainly just to prevent overcrowding of white-dots (I had it happen before and it made everything slow. And white.)

Answer (score 0):

Put the moments into an int array.

Iterate over the array searching for all true conditions. If a true condition is encountered, mark the flag as true and break the loop. In the end, if no condition is true, your flag is false.

Something like this.

```
boolean ok = false;

for ( int v : momentArray ) {
    if ( v > 60 ) {
        ok = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ( ok ) {
    // ok, do something...
}
```

Or

```
public static boolean checkForValues( int[] array, int min ) {

    for ( int v : array ) {
        if ( v > min ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}


// in another class...

if ( checkForValues( momentArray, 60 ) ) {
    // ok, do something...
}
```

I'm assuming that all of conditions is the same. If they are different you can generalize the code too, but you will nedd to create a classe to store the conditions... It does not worth the work, so its preferable to code the conditions.

Another thing. You have just tree values. If you have lots of values (with the same condition) I think the iteration would be nice, but in your scenario, I think its better to code every condition because is easier to understand the code as Ghost said.

[]'s

Comment: Thanks, I think I will stick with the long if statement for now (it's only 3 variables and creating a whole class is a bit of an overkill). But this is useful for future ideas I have, and now I know why dot's weren't drawing (mixed up > with <).

Answer (score 0):

Create a local class inside the method:

```
void myMethod ( )
{
   class Movements
   {

     float movementX = (int) (camX - sectorSize[1]);
     float movementY = (int) (camY - sectorSize[2]);
     float movementZ = (int) (camZ - sectorSize[3]);

     boolean check3Axes ( int commonValue )
     {
       return 
         movementX > commonValue
           ||
         movementY > commonValue
           ||
         movementZ > commonValue ; 
     }

     void negate (  )
     {
       if (movementX > 0) movementX *= -1;
       if (movementY > 0) movementY *= -1;
       if (movementZ > 0) movementZ *= -1;
     }
   };

   Movements m = new Movements( );

   // This can be replaced with m.negate( )
   if (m.movementX > 0) m.movementX *= -1;
   if (m.movementY > 0) m.movementY *= -1;
   if (m.movementZ > 0) m.movementZ *= -1;

   if (m.check3Axes(60))
   {   
      //do something..
   }

   if (m.check3Axes(120))
   {   
      //do something else..
   }
}
```

BTW, you may find that you can add more common methods to Movements class, such as `negate()`.

At some point, though, it may be better to make Movement a regular class.

Answer (score 0):

The inner-class looks like the best way to go. Too bad java doesn't provide anything less resource-intensive, but the ability to compare a bunch of variables with the same expression helps a lot!